# Which witch is the titular Witch’s Ghost in Scooby Doo and the Witch’s Ghost?

Tags: scooby-doo

After Shaggy and Scooby have ran away from the Hex Girls, they come across the green witch who they also run away from.

This witch is identified on the Scooby Doo wiki as “Witch’s Ghost.”

However, later on, Ben Ravencroft frees the REAL Sarah Ravencroft who is an actual ghost, and she, instead of the green witch, is seen on the cover of the film.

So which one is the ACTUAL Witch’s Ghost?

Comment: So, which witch is which witch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In this instance, the title is [deliberately ambiguous](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/162206/who-is-the-titular-heir-to-the-empire) (Like, *which witch is the witch*?).**

By the end of the film (and [tie-in storybook](https://archive.org/details/scoobydoo8x800gail)) the ghost seen during the twist-ending is called out as being the *real* witch's ghost and the witch's ghost seen at the start is outed as being fake. It follows, logically, that the title must be referring to both.

> Ben had tricked them all — the gang from Mystery Inc. the mayor and his friends, the Hex Girls. And now, his evil plans were about to unfold.
> “I will summon Sarah" Ben cried. "Together we will rule the world!"
> The book glowed red. The wind whipped fiercely, pushing everyone back. The townspeople flew into the stocks of the Puritan Village, and the Hex Girls were tied to a post.
> Thunder boomed. Lightning flashed. Clouds shifted, and suddenly the witch's ghost — the real witch's ghost — swept through the sky.
> "Serve me!" Ben commanded.
> But the witch's ghost had other ideas! "I serve no one!" She glared at Ben, holding out her arm. A fire blast shot out and caught Ben up in a green glowing ball.

[image: "Like, Which Witch is the Witch?" ZOINKS! When Scooby and the gang are invited by a famous mystery writer to the town of Oakhaven, they it's for a vacation. But when they get there, they find the once peaceful place is haunted by the ghost of a witch... or, ruh-roh! Lots of witches! Can the Mystery, Inc. gang uncover the real witch, and make the crone stand alone? Scooby-Dooby-Doo - we need some help from you now!]